# An interpolation between two files

Tags: awk, interpolation

I always appreciate your help. I am an electrical engineer. I am using a tool for timing analysis of a circuit. I would like to interpolate results from two timing reports at different voltages (0.945V and 0.78V). If voltage is decreased, data arrival time is increased.

For example,
At 0.945V, data arrival time  is 0.70
At 0.78V, data arrival time is 0.72

I wanted to know voltage when the data arrival time reaches 0.714 using a linear interpolation.

In this case, I could calculate 
(0.78-0.945)/(0.72-0.70)*0.714+(0.945-0.70*(0.78-0.945)/(0.72-0.70))

Voltage information such 0.78, 0.945 and the target data arrival time 0.714 are fixed. However, data arrival times at 0.945V and 0.78V are changed.

There is one more requirement.  If data arrival time at 0.945V is above 0.714, then output is 0.714.

0p945.rpt_in:

```
  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[23]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: ifu_exu_aluop_d[0]
               (output port)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[23] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U533/Y (INVX16_LVT)                             0.52       0.52 r
  U739/Y (AND4X1_LVT)                             0.07       0.58 r
  U572/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.05       0.64 f
  U607/Y (INVX0_LVT)                              0.04       0.68 r
  U609/Y (AO221X1_LVT)                            0.02       0.70 r
  ifu_exu_aluop_d[0] (out)                        0.00       0.70 r
  data arrival time                                          0.70
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)


  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[21]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: imsk_ff_q_reg_0_
               (rising edge-triggered flip-flop clocked by rclk)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U613/Y (INVX8_LVT)                              0.44       0.44 r
  U702/Y (XOR2X1_LVT)                             0.08       0.52 r
  U984/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.04       0.56 f
  U604/Y (OR3X1_LVT)                              0.05       0.61 f
  U605/Y (AO22X1_LVT)                             0.04       0.65 f
  U986/Y (NOR4X1_LVT)                             0.06       0.71 r
  imsk_ff_q_reg_0_/D (DFFX1_LVT)                  0.02       0.73 r
  data arrival time                                          0.73
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)
.
.
.
```

0p78.rpt_in:

```
  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[23]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: ifu_exu_aluop_d[0]
               (output port)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[23] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U533/Y (INVX16_LVT)                             0.52       0.52 r
  U739/Y (AND4X1_LVT)                             0.07       0.58 r
  U572/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.05       0.64 f
  U607/Y (INVX0_LVT)                              0.04       0.68 r
  U609/Y (AO221X1_LVT)                            0.05       0.72 r
  ifu_exu_aluop_d[0] (out)                        0.00       0.72 r
  data arrival time                                          0.72
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)


  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[21]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: imsk_ff_q_reg_0_
               (rising edge-triggered flip-flop clocked by rclk)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U613/Y (INVX8_LVT)                              0.44       0.44 r
  U702/Y (XOR2X1_LVT)                             0.08       0.52 r
  U984/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.04       0.56 f
  U604/Y (OR3X1_LVT)                              0.05       0.61 f
  U605/Y (AO22X1_LVT)                             0.04       0.65 f
  U986/Y (NOR4X1_LVT)                             0.06       0.71 r
  imsk_ff_q_reg_0_/D (DFFX1_LVT)                  0.05       0.76 r
  data arrival time                                          0.76
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)
.
.
.
```

Output.rpt_in needs to be:

```
Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[23]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: ifu_exu_aluop_d[0]
               (output port)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[23] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U533/Y (INVX16_LVT)                             0.52       0.52 r
  U739/Y (AND4X1_LVT)                             0.07       0.58 r
  U572/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.05       0.64 f
  U607/Y (INVX0_LVT)                              0.04       0.68 r
  U609/Y (AO221X1_LVT)                            0.05       0.72 r
  ifu_exu_aluop_d[0] (out)                        0.00       0.72 r
  data arrival time                                          0.8295
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)


  Startpoint: dtu_inst_d[21]
               (input port)
  Endpoint: imsk_ff_q_reg_0_
               (rising edge-triggered flip-flop clocked by rclk)
  Path Group: (none)
  Path Type: max

  Point                                           Incr       Path
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  input external delay                            0.00       0.00 f
  dtu_inst_d[21] (in)                             0.00       0.00 f
  U613/Y (INVX8_LVT)                              0.44       0.44 r
  U702/Y (XOR2X1_LVT)                             0.08       0.52 r
  U984/Y (NAND4X0_LVT)                            0.04       0.56 f
  U604/Y (OR3X1_LVT)                              0.05       0.61 f
  U605/Y (AO22X1_LVT)                             0.04       0.65 f
  U986/Y (NOR4X1_LVT)                             0.06       0.71 r
  imsk_ff_q_reg_0_/D (DFFX1_LVT)                  0.05       0.76 r
  data arrival time                                          0.714
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (Path is unconstrained)
.
.
.
```

There are more than 1000 paths in each file. 
I think awk can do this, but I don't know how to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Jaeyoung

Comment: Yes, awk is very flexible, it may work. Can edit you Q and include a much smaller example of your data? As posted, your Q is more like a consulting spec. Good luck.

Comment: When building a house it's reasonable to ask your neighbor to borrow a hammer. It's unreasonable to hand them the plans and ask them to build the house for you while you sit back and read a newspaper. Edit your post to create a reasonable question that will help you on your way to solving your problem. Thanks, the neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, you are mixing time and voltage! 0.714 is a time while 0.8295 is a voltage!

```
awk -v time=0.714 '
FNR==1 {
i_file++;
V[i_file] = gensub(/0p([0-9]+)\.rpt_in/, "\\1", "g", FILENAME)}

FNR==NR && /data arrival time/ {i_time_1++; time_1[i_time_1] = $4}

FNR!=NR && /data arrival time/ {i_time_2++; time_2[i_time_2] = $4;
$4 = TO_BE_MODIFIED}

FNR!=NR {print $0}' 0p945.rpt_in 0p78.rpt_in
```

First you can store time as a variable `-v`.
Then you can extract voltage `V` value `[0-9]+` using `gensub` on `FILENAME`.
Then you get `data arrival time` as the 4th column variable `$4` for the first file `FNR==NR`, and for the second one `FNR!=NR` where you directly change the interpolated time `$4`, and print every line `$0`.

For more readability, I let you add the `if` conditions to modify the interpolated time `$4` for higher times. Always use `i_time_2` since your are currently reading the 2nd file.

Comment: Thank you for code.

I have found a code by modifying your code. 

awk -v time=0.714 '
FNR==1 {
i_file++;
V[i_file] = gensub(/0p([0-9]+)\.rpt_in/, "\\1", "g", FILENAME)}

FNR==NR && /data arrival time/ {i_time_1++; time_1[i_time_1] = $4}

FNR!=NR && /data arrival time/ {i_time_2++; time_2[i_time_2] = $4;
$4 = -0.165 / (time_2[i_time_2]-time_1[i_time_2]) * 0.714 + (0.945 - time_1[i_time_2]* -0.165/ (time_2[i_time_2] - time_1[i_time_2])) }


FNR!=NR {print $0}' 0p945.rpt_noio2 0p78.rpt_noio2

Comment: You are welcome Jaeyoung. Please edit your answer by formatting your code with \`\` for further readers.